# Create array from row objects in the same table :: PHP + SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have an array like so

```
id | userID | item
1  ! 1      | {"property": 0, "property": "string"}
2  ! 1      | {"property": 4, "property": "string2"}
```

and I wish to return one array with like so:

```
[{
    "property": 0, 
    "property": "string"
}, 
{
    "property": 4,
    "property": "string2"
}]
```

No matter what I try I cannot seem to get it to work properly. Either I get a whole string so number values get converted, or I get an object with \" everywhere. Currently I have this code

```
if ($query = $mysqli->query("SELECT item FROM userItems WHERE userID = 'id' "))
{
    while ($row = $query->fetch_object())
    {
        $result->items[count($result)] = $row;
    }
}

$test = stripslashes(json_encode($result->items));
```

which returns this ...

```
{"1":{"item":"{"property":"0","property":"string"}"}}
```

Been trying to solve it for hours and can't get it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and there're two main things:

1. you're building an array of associative arrays but associative array tends to overwrite identical associative keys with the latter in your code - in your case both keys are `property`,
2. the data you're retrieving from DB (userItems.item) already seems to be JSON encoded so you need to call `json_decode()` somewhere instead of calling `json_encode()` again; decoding your `$row->item` (`$result->items[count($result)] = json_decode($row->item);`) seems to do the trick.

Just as a sidenote you should consider wrapping your `id` parameter in SQL query into `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or so.

Let me know if that helped and you see the desired result now.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it tomorrow, too tired for today haha. I do use $mysqli->real_escape_string() but I omitted it to take up less space